# What's the API Name for the "Create Public Links" profile permission?

Tags: profile

I am trying to look for the API name for "Create Public Links", I would assume it would look something like "PermissionsCreatePublicLinks" but I cannot seem to find anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Name for `Create Public Links` on both `Profile` and `PermissionSet` is:

> PermissionsChatterFileLink

*I validated it on both profile and a custom permission set.*